# How to get a Strategy to alter the entry quantity based on how the last closed trade performed (profit or lose)

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I can't figure out how to change the buy or sell Entry quantity based on whether the last closed trade was a winner or loser.  Example:  If last closed trade was a winner then the next Entry qty is 1, if the last closed trade was a loser/loss then the next trade entry qty would be 2.  I tried using
the following but it does not work. The trade entry qty stays a 1 no matter what the previous closed trade P/L is.

```
var revQuantity = 0

if strategy.closedtrades.profit(strategy.closedtrades - 1) < 0
   revQuantity = 2
else
   revQuantity = 1

strategy.entry("long", strategy.long, qty = revQuantity)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the following, it is working as intended:

```
var bool loss_trade = false

if (strategy.losstrades > strategy.losstrades[1])
    loss_trade := true
if (strategy.wintrades > strategy.wintrades[1])
    loss_trade := false

if (long_entry_condition and loss_trade)
    strategy.entry("Long-Last_Was_Loss", strategy.long, qty = 2)
if (long_entry_condition and not loss_trade)
    strategy.entry("Long-Last_Was_Profit", strategy.long, qty = 1)
```

Comment: this works well, with one exception, when there is a reverse position on same bar (i.e short trade was loser, next trade is a long position executed on close of same bar as short exit) .  I'll try a few things to see if I can fix. may enter new trade at open of next bar. again, thanks for the good help.